# How to create 2D compound body shapes with offset and rotation in Urho3D?

Tags: urho3d

I want to attach two shapes together so that their relative position stays always constant.

The shapes must be placed at specific offsets relative to the center of the node.

In Box2D, this can be achieved by making multiple fixtures as mentioned at: [How to combine Box2d bodies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35667232/how-to-combine-box2d-bodies/47848713#47848713) , and then using the `shape.m_p.Set`.

I have managed to do it in 3D by:

- calling `Node::CreateComponent<CollisionCircle2D>` multiple times
- using the `CollistionShape::SetPosition` method to set the offset

Minimal runnable example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/Urho3D-cheat/blob/76134e9e53e82a95447701f4a67646d47a76d320/compound3d.cpp#L101

However in 2D, I could not find an analogue to `SetPosition` in the `CollisionShape2D` class, so all the shapes are co-centric, which I don't want. Minimal example: https://github.com/cirosantilli/Urho3D-cheat/blob/76134e9e53e82a95447701f4a67646d47a76d320/compound.cpp#L35

Answer (score 0):

**`CollisionCircle2D::SetCenter`**

For some reason, the analogous method is not on the base class `CollisionShape2D`, but rather on the derived classes, e.g. `CollisionCircle2D::SetCenter`.

The `CollisionCircle2D::SetCenter` method takes a `Vector2D` parameter that behaves just like `CollistionShape::SetPosition`.

Working code at: https://github.com/cirosantilli/Urho3D-cheat/blob/4a03873e40ef83b488bb8ca36d6f35c5d046de28/compound.cpp#L44

Yet question self answered while asking :-)